# NPM: Why is this package installed?

Tags: node.js, npm

How do I determine why a particular package is installed?  In other words, what package(s) depend on this package?

The package in question is babelify.  `npm ls` shows it at the top level, but it is not included in package.json anywhere.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Use `npm ls` to list installed packages and see the dependency graph of a given package eg:

```
> npm ls core-js

my_module /path/to/my_module>
└─┬ pug@2.0.4
  └─┬ pug-code-gen@2.0.2
    └─┬ constantinople@3.1.2
      └─┬ babel-types@6.26.0
        └─┬ babel-runtime@6.26.0
          └── core-js@2.6.10
```

Answer (score 25):

`npm explain <package name>` is what you're looking for. It *explains* why a package is in your node_modules folder by showing a "bottoms up" view. See docs [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-explain)

Comment: Note, that this is not available to npm versions < 7

Comment: npm explain is also what the official Yarn documentation is referring to: https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/migrating-from-npm#toc-cli-commands-comparison

Answer (score 23):

As you mention, `npm ls` (short for 'list') shows packages and their dependencies:

```
> npm ls leveldown
appless@5.0.0 C:\Users\mikem\Code\appless
`-- @architect/architect@5.7.0
  `-- dynalite@2.2.0
    `-- UNMET OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY leveldown@4.0.2
```

**If `npm ls` shows it at the top level, and it is not a dependency in the top level `package.json`, it's likely was previously required and is now no longer used.**

Use [`npm prune` to remove the unused package](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/prune).

Answer (score 10):

There's a module called [`npm-why`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-why) which identifies why a package has been installed.

Of course, if you're using `yarn`, you have a built-in command [`yarn why`](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/why/).

Comment: npm-why is exactly what I was looking for. beautifully just shows this depends on that, depends on what you're asking about, thanks!

Comment: This is also what I was scouring the web for. Unlike `npm explain`, `npm-why` can work off just a `package-lock.json` file

Answer (score 3):

If you can't find a `require` or `import`, try looking at child `package.json`s to see who else needs it.

**(Note:  `find` requires Linux/macOS, this won't work on Windows)**

`find . -name package.json  -exec grep -l babelify /dev/null {} \;`

```
./node_modules/browserify-zlib/package.json
./node_modules/cssnext/package.json
./node_modules/cypress/dist/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/packages/reporter/package.json
./node_modules/cypress/dist/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/packages/server/node_modules/@cypress/browserify-preprocessor/package.json
./node_modules/cypress/dist/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/packages/server/node_modules/async/package.json
./node_modules/cypress/dist/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/packages/server/node_modules/babel-core/package.json
./node_modules/cypress/dist/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/packages/server/node_modules/babelify/package.json
./node_modules/cypress/dist/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/packages/server/node_modules/getos/node_modules/async/package.json
./node_modules/cypress/dist/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/packages/server/node_modules/object-assign/package.json
./node_modules/cypress/dist/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/packages/server/node_modules/watchify/node_modules/browserify-zlib/package.json
./node_modules/cypress/dist/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/packages/server/package.json
./node_modules/eslint/package.json
./node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin/node_modules/async/package.json
./node_modules/getos/node_modules/async/package.json
./node_modules/postcss-modules-extract-imports/package.json
./node_modules/postcss-modules-scope/package.json
./node_modules/webpack/node_modules/async/package.json
```

Answer (score 1):

My one-liner, based on other answers: `npm ls | grep -C 10 PACKAGE`

Replace PACKAGE with the package you're looking for. This is simpler and faster than other suggestions. The shell is your friend, friends!

**Breakdown/Explanation**

- `npm ls` - As explained above, this prints the dependency tree representation of your app.
- `|` - The secret sauce of *nix shells. This sends the output to the next program, instead of printing it.
- `grep [...] PACKAGE` - Search for the string "PACKAGE" (This is actually regex, but that's irrelevant.)
- `-C 10` - This tells grep to print 10 extra lines around the matching lines. Without this, grep would only print the lines were PACKAGE was found. Increasing this number gives you more context. If `-C` doesn't work on your system (less common linux versions), try using `-B 10 -A 10` instead. It's a more verbose way of doing the same thing: "10 lines before, 10 lines after."