# How to find an npm package that depends on gulp-browserify-thin?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I'm trying to run `npm install` on a work project with a lot of packages that are not up to date. I get the following error:

```
npm ERR! npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/gulp-browserify-thin
/-/gulp-browserify-thin-0.1.5.tgz - Not found
npm ERR! npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! npm ERR! 404  'gulp-browserify-thin@https://registry.npmjs.org/gulp-browserify- 
thin/-/gulp-browserify-thin-0.1.5.tgz' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
```

The gulp-browserify-thin package was recently removed from npm because of some malicious code.
There's no reference to this package in the project, so I suppose that one of the project packages (probably not the latest version of the package) depends on it, and I have no idea which package it is. Is there a way find out?

Comment: `npm ls <package>`? See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/36049577/3001761.

Comment: @jonrsharpe it returns 'empty'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NPM: Why is this package installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36049577/npm-why-is-this-package-installed)

Answer (score 0):

Check the package-lock.json. You should be able to find the missing package listed as required for whichever package is depending on it.

Comment: As I said, there is no references to the gulp-browserify-thin package in the project at all.