# TypeError: pathRegexp is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, postgresql, express

I'm trying to run some tests in my project by using jest, However I'm getting an error code while on the process not related to the tests itself. more like a dependency or node express compatibility error

```
`● Test suite failed to run

TypeError: pathRegexp is not a function

   6 | 
   7 | 
>  8 | app.use(express.json());
     |     ^
   9 | 
  10 | const authRoutes = require('./routes/auth');
  11 | const userRoutes = require('./routes/users');

  at new Layer (bankly/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:45:17)
  at Function.use (bankly/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:475:17)
  at Function.lazyrouter (bankly/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:151:18)
  at Function.use (bankly/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:221:8)
  at Object.<anonymous> (bankly/app.js:8:5)
  at Object.<anonymous> (bankly/__tests__/routes.test.js:6:13)

  Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 passed, 2 total
  Tests:       5 passed, 5 total
  Snapshots:   0 total
  Time:        0.397 s, estimated 1 s
  Ran all test suites.`
```

I've been reviewing this error for a while now and can't seem to find a solution, already tried to update dependencies, downgrade some of them. re-install express and node. Nothing of that seemed to work.

Comment: Sounds like you've managed to install path-to-regex v6 or later which is [not compatible with Express v4](https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/4136)

Comment: Should i downgrade path-to-regex to a old version instead? or newer? @Phil

Comment: The question is, why is it not the version required by Express?

Comment: No idea, I have the package.json file as part of a coding project and the version listed on file is "^4.18.2". path-to-regex is used as a sub-dependency as how it is not listed under "dependencies" @Phil

Comment: Express v4.18.2 (latest stable) expects [path-to-regexp@0.1.7](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/4.18.2/package.json#L50). What version do you have installed? Use [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36049577/283366) to find out

Comment: I can see that I have the required version which is 0.1.7. I guess it could also be related on how my tests are set up? @Phil

Comment: NVM I fixed it.

Comment: How? Please add an answer below if you feel it could help somebody else in future